# SelfPopulatingCache incumbent cache issue (Spring 4, EhCache 2.10.3)

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I have a project setup *(the snippets here are from a demo project I have created on GitHub https://github.com/ashishmarwal/self-populating-cache-issue)* where a raw eh-cache cache is declared in the ehcache config (ehcache.xml).

```
<cache name="alphabet-description-cache"
       eternal="false"
       maxElementsInMemory="1000"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
       overflowToDisk="false"
       timeToLiveSeconds="300"
       timeToIdleSeconds="300" />
```

Spring bean descriptor then uses that raw cache to create a decorated (SelfPopulatingCache) using a CacheEntryFactory:

```
<bean id="springCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
</bean>

<!--Creating a decorated cache instance using the raw cache cinfigured in ehcache.xml -->
<bean id="alphabetDescriptionCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
    <property name="cacheName" value="alphabet-description-cache"/>
    <property name="cacheEntryFactory" ref="alphabetDescriptionCacheEntryFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="alphabetDescriptionCacheEntryFactory" class="com.marwals.ashish.issues.selfpopulatingcache.AlphabetDescriptionCacheEntryFactory" />
```

We also have a test-context.xml which is used for unit testing and declares a cacheManager as well as the decorated cache (in my perspective I have given different names to these cache managers):

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="cacheManagerName" value="self-populating-cache-issue-demo-test"/>
    <property name="shared" value="true"/>
    <property name="acceptExisting" value="false"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="springCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="alphabetDescriptionCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
    <property name="cacheName" value="alphabet-description-cache"/>
    <property name="cacheEntryFactory" ref="alphabetDescriptionCacheEntryFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="alphabetDescriptionCacheEntryFactory" class="com.marwals.ashish.issues.selfpopulatingcache.AlphabetDescriptionCacheEntryFactory" />
```

The problem here is that if I have two different tests each loading either the main or the test-context bean descriptor, I run into an incumbent cache issue:

```
    Error creating bean with name 'alphabetDescriptionCache' defined in class path resource [test-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Cannot replace alphabet-description-cache It does not equal the incumbent cache.
```

Any ideas what could be wrong here? Debugging the code reveals that I have two different cache instance for the same raw cache which is then raised as an error by EhCache's cache manager.

I have created a git repo demonstrating this problem:
https://github.com/ashishmarwal/self-populating-cache-issue

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You explicitly requested a shared cache manager in your Spring configuration

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="cacheManagerName" value="self-populating-cache-issue-demo"/>
    <property name="shared" value="true"/> <!-- here -->
    <property name="acceptExisting" value="false"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
```

This means Ehcache will always return the same `CacheManager` for a given configuration. In your case (and generally) you don't want that.

Just setting `shared` to `false` solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Henri. I will try this out. My real scenario has a bunch of tests with a test spring context while a few with a real spring context. So after discussing it with a few people here I realized the ones using the real spring context should have been declared integration tests and run separate from the VM forked by surefire for running the unit tests.

Comment: In general you don't need a shared cache manager because you will have a shared spring application context. Which will transitively providing a shared cache manager. So any way you are going, the cache manager should be shared.